# How to rearrange structure and type of an imported dataset?

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I have a bigger dataset imported from Excel. Its elements have a form of {time, data}.
Day is irrelevant and I would like to have the time in decimal form e.g. 10:30 is 10.5

```
sampledata={{"24/09/2014 00:00", 4.}, {"24/09/2014 00:15", 4.},
  {"24/09/2014 00:30", 6.}, {"24/09/2014 00:45", 10.},
  {"24/09/2014 01:00", 10.}, {"24/09/2014 01:15", 12.},
  {"24/09/2014 01:30", 11.}, {"24/09/2014 01:45", 14.},
  {"24/09/2014 02:00", 21.}, {"24/09/2014 02:15", 18.},
  {"24/09/2014 02:30", 27.}, {"24/09/2014 02:45", 12.},
  {"24/09/2014 03:00", 13.}, {"24/09/2014 03:15", 16.},
  {"24/09/2014 03:30", 43.}, {"24/09/2014 03:45", 76.},
  {"24/09/2014 04:00", 46.}, {"24/09/2014 04:15", 53.},
  {"24/09/2014 04:30", 63.}, {"24/09/2014 04:45", 46.},
  {"24/09/2014 05:00", 37.}, {"24/09/2014 05:15", 47.}}
```

I have a really ugly solution.

```
((sampledata/. {a_, b_} :> {StringSplit[a], b}) /. {{x_, y_}, 
  z_} :>  {ToExpression@StringSplit[y, ":"], z}) /. {{p_, q_}, 
    r_} -> {p + q/60., r}
```

It works, but I am curious if it is possible to do it in one step.

Comment: What do you mean with "one step" exactly? Performing the conversion on `Import` or a simpler way for the conversion itself?

Comment: I meant simpler conversion, one replacement or one simpler function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you strive for a clean one-liner to do the work, maybe this will help:

```
{DateList@#1/.{__,h_,m_,_}:>h+m/60.,#2}&@@@sampledata
```

giving you

```
{{0., 4.}, {0.25, 4.}, {0.5, 6.}, {0.75, 10.}, {1., 10.}, {1.25, 
  12.}, {1.5, 11.}, {1.75, 14.}, {2., 21.}, {2.25, 18.}, {2.5, 
  27.}, {2.75, 12.}, {3., 13.}, {3.25, 16.}, {3.5, 43.}, {3.75, 
  76.}, {4., 46.}, {4.25, 53.}, {4.5, 63.}, {4.75, 46.}, {5., 
  37.}, {5.25, 47.}}
```

Should you have interest in the contribution of seconds, you might adjust this to

```
{DateList@#1/.{__,h_,m_,s_}:>h+(s/60.+m)/60.,#2}&@@@sampledata
```

I hope to have been of some help to you.

Answer (score 2):

This is close, just need to `NumberFormat` in decimal:

```
data = sampledata // Dataset;

data[All, 
 Query[{QuantityMagnitude[
     TimeObject[First[#]] - TimeObject[{0, 0, 0}], "Hours"] &, Last}]]
```